# Adding time in a file name

Tags: stata, stata-macros

Consider the code snippet below:

```
local date: display %td_CCYY_NN_DD date(c(current_date), "DMY")
local date_string = subinstr(trim("`date'"), " " , "", .)
save "`date_string'_example", replace
mkdir "`date_string'_example"
```

This creates output as follows:

```
20170521_example.dta
```

However, I want to create a file name which also has time, not just date. If the time is 4PM 25 min 01 sec, then I wish to have the following:

```
20170521_162601_example.dta
```

How can I add this element?

I tried putting `c(current_time)` inside the `date()` function but that did not work.

Also, I tried to assign a local macro `savedir` using the `date_string`. However, it seems Stata can't recognise it when it is followed by `\`:

```
local date: display %td_CCYY_NN_DD date(c(current_date), "DMY")
local date_string = subinstr(trim("`date'"), " " , "", .)
local savedir "C:\Users\`date_string'_output"
cd "`savedir'
```

What should I do to save the local macro `savedir`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the desired output as follows:

```
local datetime_string : display %tc_CCYYNNDD_HHMMSS clock(c(current_date) + " " + ///
                         c(current_time), "DMYhms")
```

As regards to your second question, just replace `\` in your
file path with `/`.

Forward slashes can be used in Stata
for file paths on all operating systems, and Stata will take care to translate
them correctly on Windows.